# How can I restrict the version of the target DB instance in a SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

How can I restrict an SSIS Package to only execute on SQL Server 2012?

Is there a built-in way to do this (metadata?), or do I need to do a query?

*(Possibly belongs in a new question)*:

I can get the version using `SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')`, but how do I verify that it is `like '11.%'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an initial `Execute SQL Task` in the Control Flow and use the following code in it:

```
IF ((SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as CHAR(2))) = 11)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'TRUE' As Result
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT 'FALSE' As Result
```

You can of course do several things with this, one of the easiest and clearest for SSIS developers would be to store the results in a SSIS variable and assign the Precedent Constraint after the SQL Task to `Expression and Constraint`.

If the `Execute SQL Task` Succeeds and returns TRUE it will allow the rest of the execution, which could be a single package, part of a larger execution stream, or a master package. If it fails or returns FALSE your package stops... might be worth putting in another path for an alert message or log of this though.

You can also use `(SELECT @@VERSION) LIKE 'Microsoft SQL Server 2014%'`. I like this as it's a more familiar version nomenclature.

Comment: I approve of the general approach but I think you're going to have a much more painful experience with using @@server. Way too much text and permutations therein to deal with. I think they'd be much better served by retrieving the value as the OP originally thought of `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS ProductVersion` and then apply your logic via precedence constraints